# Check if a url is a PDF file or an image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I have the following URLs.

This is an image url:

```
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534294228306-bd54eb9a7ba8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8OHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80
```

And this is a PDF file url:

```
http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf
```

I want to know which url is for an image and which one is for PDF using JavaScript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have CORS set up to these endpoints? If so, issue a HEAD request and watch out for the `content-type` header in the response. Without CORS, options are more limited.

Comment: Adding to @spender answer - without CORS you could download the file and look at it's mime type which could be extracted when encoding the file in base64 format

Comment: I don't see a way to do this from the client side; the browser is quite strict about JS loading resources, and http / non-cors stuff is not going to work on a https site.